Why is "for" preceded by a comma when it is used in the same way as "because"?
It seems that when "for" is used essentially as a subordinating conjunction even though it's supposedly a coordinating conjunction (correct me if I'm wrong on that), it's preceded by a comma despite the usual advice not to do so for subordinating conjunctions.
Take this example:

I had to stay with my wicked stepmother, for I had nowhere else to go.


I had to stay with my wicked stepmother because I had nowhere else to go.

It seems here that "for" means "for the reason that" and connects a subordinate clause.
I understand that "because" can also act as a coordinating conjunction. From the OED definition of this use:

Followed by a complete clause. Sometimes used to express the reason for the statement made in the main clause." This makes sense to me. "Because" here means "as evidenced by the fact that..."

And "for" can also take the same meaning. OED:

Introducing a new clause or series of clauses stating the ground or reason for something previously said: seeing that, since. Now somewhat literary."

E.g.

The lady must be very generous, because she helped me out.


The lady must be very generous, for she helped me out.

So it seems that "for" can be used interchangeably with "because" in this definition (as a coordinating conjunction meaning "as evidenced by the fact that").
But when "for" is used as (essentially) a subordinating conjunction, should the comma not be dropped:

I had to stay with my wicked stepmother for I had nowhere else to go.

Any and all thoughts appreciated. Sorry if it's rambling.

Some people try to establish rules about comma use, but there's so many differences of opinion (see all the questions here). Use a comma if you think a pause would be necessary or if it's long and confusing (e.g. if you use "for" for other purposes elsewhere in the sentence.) But I find this use of "for" slightly old-fashioned, so most of your examples may likewise be old-fashioned (wicked stepmothers and ladies) and not reflect modern punctuation styles.

@StuartF Thanks for your thoughts.

There's a lot of documentation here about "for." I feel like the part that's missing is "despite the usual advice not to do so for subordinating conjunctions." Sez who? Where did you find this advice? I just dedicated 15 seconds to googling "don't use a comma before subordinating conjunctions" and the first three results say "you don't have to use one." One result says "If a sentence is very long and complicated, however, a comma before a subordinating conjunction may be warranted." If you edit to tell more about your source, there can be better answers explaining or refuting it.

Compare sentences: "I am waiting, for the weather changed." (for = conjunction, changed = past tense), "I am waiting for the weather changed." (for = preposition, changed = past participle) :) . In first sentence, change of the weather has already occurred, while in second sentence, change of the weather has not yet occurred.

@Artfever That would be 'I am waiting for the weather to change' except in centuries-old poetry.

Punctuation is up to the writer, and though the vast majority of cases will find a comma (or semicolon, or colon) before 'for' when it introduces an unmarked finite declarative clause (something that could stand on its own as a complete sentence) and plays the role of an adjunct of reason (replaceable by 'because'), there are counter examples to be found.

Ah, my Mother, leave me not in my own hands for I should then be
lost. (Grace to You)
I began to feel that it was unwise of me to go any farther into the
wide field of hypotheses for I should certainly have revived some
difficulty, or rather impossibility, that would have enraged the
Professor. (A Journey to the Center of the Earth, Jules Verne)
I hope we shall be old Fritz before long anyhow for I should like
to get back for a while before I’m an old man. (Letters Home WW1)
Believe me for I should know since I looked him in the eye as I
asked for reasons why, but he ignored me and chose the crowd instead.
(Iowa Starting Line)
Nationalism can not be purely economic or technological for it
would spell suicide yet cultural nationalism often appears as a viable
alternative, a way to regain the control lost in other spheres. (ACAD:
American Studies International ; Jun97, Vol. 35 Issue 2, p30, 22p;
Guerlain, Pierre)

As usual, the advice in style guides does come from somewhere, whether prescriptivist ideas about what the language should look like when represented in text, or simple descriptive observations of what the language does look like most of the time when represented in text. In this case, the data is heavily in favor of a comma before 'for', and any argument to the contrary, however well reasoned, will produce results that will look unconventional (see the above).
So, the answer to your question is that no the comma before 'for' should not be dropped in the majority of cases, at least not if you'd like to follow established convention.

The comma there represents the prosody of the spoken phrase; the pause there differentiates  for as conjunction from for as preposition. There is a naturally occuring syntactic pause at the clause boundary.

I had to stay with my wicked stepmother for the summer.
I had to stay with my wicked stepmother, for I had nowhere else to go.

because was originally a prepositional phrase, BTW.  Prosody (the  rhythms of syntax, the resulting phrasal contours) are resistant to diachronic change. Many of the  syntactic rhythms in modern-day English are identical to those used over a thousand years ago.
Here are a couple of examples, and I could provided hundreds of them:

He thought if the Downs had the same chance as the half-breds, and they let them have the best food, farmers would be able to carry more sheep per acre. This, however, was speculation, for he had not tried it.
He acquitted of all blame the honourable gentleman who was the leader of the Council, for he had not been responsible for this ...


Thus, even under Lynn's view of things he could not have been considered a regular full time employee, for he had not averaged 35 hours per week.

